# Trial experience of app is allowing unrestricted access - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, trial

I launched my first app yesterday to the store. The app has a trial version which simply restricts full access to the game.

I downloaded the trial and played for a while, no problems - good.

I then purchased the full version by from the store and started the app again only to find that it didnt release it's restrited areas - NOT good.

I have implemented the following code in the app to implement the restrictions:

```
/// <summary>
/// The TrialExperienceHelper class can serve as a convenient building-block in your app's trial experience implementation. It queries
/// the license as infrequently as possible, and caches the results, for maximum performance. When built in debug configuration, the class simulates the purchase
/// experience when the Buy method is called. To customize what happens in debug when Buy is called, initialize the simulatedLicMode and/or
/// simulatedLicModeOnPurchase fields to different values. A release build of this class will have access to a license only when the app is
/// published to the Windows Phone Store. For a release build not published to the Store, the value of the LicenseMode property will be
/// LicenseModes.MissingOrRevoked.
/// </summary>
public static class TrialExperienceHelper
{
    #region enums
    /// <summary>
    /// The LicenseModes enumeration describes the mode of a license.
    /// </summary>
    public enum LicenseModes
    {
        Full,
        MissingOrRevoked,
        Trial
    }
    #endregion enums

    #region fields
#if DEBUG
    // Determines how a debug build behaves on launch. This field is set to LicenseModes.Full after simulating a purchase.
    // Calling the Buy method (or navigating away from the app and back) will simulate a purchase.
    internal static LicenseModes simulatedLicMode = LicenseModes.Trial;
#endif // DEBUG
    private static bool isActiveCache;
    private static bool isTrialCache;
    #endregion fields

    #region constructors
    // The static constructor effectively initializes the cache of the state of the license when the app is launched. It also attaches
    // a handler so that we can refresh the cache whenever the license has (potentially) changed.
    static TrialExperienceHelper()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.RefreshCache();
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.Activated += (object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e) => TrialExperienceHelper.
#if DEBUG
            // In debug configuration, when the user returns to the application we will simulate a purchase.
OnSimulatedPurchase();
#else // DEBUG
            // In release configuration, when the user returns to the application we will refresh the cache.
RefreshCache();
#endif // DEBUG
    }
    #endregion constructors

    #region properties
    /// <summary>
    /// The LicenseMode property combines the active and trial states of the license into a single
    /// enumerated value. In debug configuration, the simulated value is returned. In release configuration,
    /// if the license is active then it is either trial or full. If the license is not active then
    /// it is either missing or revoked.
    /// </summary>
    public static LicenseModes LicenseMode
    {
        get
        {
#if DEBUG
            return simulatedLicMode;
#else // DEBUG
            if (TrialExperienceHelper.isActiveCache)
            {
                return TrialExperienceHelper.isTrialCache ? LicenseModes.Trial : LicenseModes.Full;
            }
            else // License is inactive.
            {
                return LicenseModes.MissingOrRevoked;
            }
#endif // DEBUG
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The IsFull property provides a convenient way of checking whether the license is full or not.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsFull
    {
        get
        {
            return (TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode == LicenseModes.Full);
        }
    }
    #endregion properties

    #region methods
    /// <summary>
    /// The Buy method can be called when the license state is trial. the user is given the opportunity
    /// to buy the app after which, in all configurations, the Activated event is raised, which we handle.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Buy()
    {
        MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
        marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
        marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method can be called at any time to refresh the values stored in the cache. We re-query the application object
    /// for the current state of the license and cache the fresh values. We also raise the LicenseChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RefreshCache()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.isActiveCache = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.IsActive;
        TrialExperienceHelper.isTrialCache = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.IsTrial;
        TrialExperienceHelper.RaiseLicenseChanged();
    }

    private static void RaiseLicenseChanged()
    {
        if (TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseChanged != null)
        {
            TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseChanged();
        }
    }

#if DEBUG
    private static void OnSimulatedPurchase()
    {
        TrialExperienceHelper.simulatedLicMode = LicenseModes.Full;
        TrialExperienceHelper.RaiseLicenseChanged();
    }
#endif // DEBUG
    #endregion methods

    #region events
    /// <summary>
    /// The static LicenseChanged event is raised whenever the value of the LicenseMode property has (potentially) changed.
    /// </summary>
    public static event LicenseChangedEventHandler LicenseChanged;
    #endregion events
}
```

Then in my code I'm using if's to determine what to allow with this:

```
    if ((TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode == TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseModes.Trial)||
    (TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseMode == TrialExperienceHelper.LicenseModes.MissingOrRevoked))
{
    //Then add ad' etc
}
```

This call must be returning TRUE...!

For the life of me I can't see the mistake, maybe someone here more experienced can help? What have I done wrong here?

Comment: did you test the app via beta distribution first?

Comment: @NeilTurner no, Will do in the future